# ERROR ContextCleaner: Error in cleaning thread

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a project with spark 1.4.1 and scala 2.11, when I run it with sbt run ( sbt 0.13.12) it display an error is the following:

```
16/12/22 15:36:43 ERROR ContextCleaner: Error in cleaning thread
java.lang.InterruptedException
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:135)
        at org.apache.spark.ContextCleaner$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$ContextCleaner$$keepCleaning$1.apply$mcV$sp(ContextCleaner.scala:175)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrStopSparkContext(Utils.scala:1249)
        at org.apache.spark.ContextCleaner.org$apache$spark$ContextCleaner$$keepCleaning(ContextCleaner.scala:172)
        at org.apache.spark.ContextCleaner$$anon$1.run(ContextCleaner.scala:67)
16/12/22 15:36:43 ERROR Utils: uncaught error in thread SparkListenerBus, stopping SparkContext
java.lang.InterruptedException
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:996)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1303)
        at java.util.concurrent.Semaphore.acquire(Semaphore.java:317)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(LiveListenerBus.scala:80)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(LiveListenerBus.scala:79)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(LiveListenerBus.scala:79)
        at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(LiveListenerBus.scala:78)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrStopSparkContext(Utils.scala:1249)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus$$anon$1.run(LiveListenerBus.scala:77)

Exception: sbt.TrapExitSecurityException thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "run-main-0"
16/12/22 15:36:43 ERROR ContextCleaner: Error in cleaning thread
java.lang.InterruptedException
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:135)
        at org.apache.spark.ContextCleaner$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$ContextCleaner$$keepCleaning$1.apply$mcV$sp(ContextCleaner.scala:175)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrStopSparkContext(Utils.scala:1249)
        at org.apache.spark.ContextCleaner.org$apache$spark$ContextCleaner$$keepCleaning(ContextCleaner.scala:172)
        at org.apache.spark.ContextCleaner$$anon$1.run(ContextCleaner.scala:67)
```

Knowing that I stopped the object of spark (sc.stop() ) at the end of my code, but I still got the same error. May be there is insufficient memory, I changed the configuration to a executor memory than the driver memory, in the following:

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Simple project").setMaster("local[*]").set("spark.executor.memory", "2g")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
```

But always I have the same error.
Can you help me by an ideas, where's exactly my error, in the configuration of the memory or another thing ?

Comment: Does your code execute correctly? Or does this just pop up at the end?

Comment: I run a full program by sbt run, he display this error (detailled above) with a success at the end of runing,  it do not give me any result.

Answer (score 5):

> Knowing that I stopped the object of spark (sc.stop() ) at the end of my code, but I still got the same error.

Stopping the spark context (sc.stop()) without waiting for the job to complete could be the reason for this. Make sure you call sc.stop() only after calling all your spark actions.

Comment: I called the spark context in the end of my application. Excuse me, what do you mean by call sc.stop() only after calling all your spark actions ?

Comment: I meant that calling sc.stop() when the job is still running could be the reason for your issue.

Comment: I have already tried that, but in vein, I still got the same error

Comment: Could you share your driver code if possible? It is difficult to find the reason with logs as it doesn't say anything about the cause of error.

Comment: Ok, I will post it into a new question.

Comment: Is that new question available and answered any where?