# how to properly wait for termination of Spark in local mode?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am using spark in local mode:

```
trait LocalStandAloneSpark {
  val spark: SparkSession =
    SparkSession
      .builder
      .appName("local-mode-spark")
      .master("local[*]")
      .config("spark.executor.cores", 2)
      .config("spark.network.timeout", "10000001") // to avoid shutdown during debug, avoid otherwise
      .config("spark.executor.heartbeatInterval", "10000000") // to avoid shutdown during debug, avoid otherwise
      .getOrCreate()
}
```

And I'm probably not aware how to properly accomplish proper termination with error messages about interrupted operations. If I do not include `spark.stop()` at the end of my flow, [I get the error from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41287210/error-contextcleaner-error-in-cleaning-thread), and when I do include `spart.stop()` there, I get this error:

```
[org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Statistics$StatisticsDataReferenceCleaner] WARN org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem - exception in the cleaner thread but it will continue to run
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:144)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:165)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Statistics$StatisticsDataReferenceCleaner.run(FileSystem.java:3212)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I suspect that maybe the use of java's `FileUtils` for writing files as part of my code might be related, but am not sure how to go about it (I'm not explicitly using any asynchronous `FileUtils` functions).

What should I do in order to avoid that kind of error?

As much as that's relevant, I'm running my main via sbt.

Comment: Have you tried to run it in forked JVM? (in sbt add `fork in run := true`).

Comment: You are right! I thought I was using that setting but I wasn't. Care to discuss why would that matter?

Comment: This is explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44298847/why-do-we-need-to-add-fork-in-run-true-when-running-spark-sbt-application#answer-47172931).